# How to fetch only the first data from an API in React?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json, react-hooks, axios

I am currently working on a website that, when I open it, should always print a random quote from the API. However, when I open the API, it doesn't randomly display a quote in json format, but outputs all the quotes stored in an array.
My problem is that on my website all the quotes are spinning until the debugger stops for lack of memory. How can I make the map function display only the first data of the array?
My code:

```
const randomIndex = (arr) => {
    // returns a random int value to use as an index
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  };

  const [quote, setQuote] = useState("");
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  const QuoteAPI = async () => {
    let arrayOfQuotes = [];
    const data = await axios.get("https://type.fit/api/quotes");
    arrayOfQuotes = data.data;
    console.log(arrayOfQuotes);
    const quote = arrayOfQuotes.map((arrayOfQuote) => (
      <div key={arrayOfQuote.id}>
        <h3>{arrayOfQuote.text}</h3>
        <p>{arrayOfQuote.author}</p>
      </div>
    ));
    console.log(quote);
    setQuote(quote);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    QuoteAPI();
    setIndex(randomIndex(quote));
  }, [quote]);
```

Comment: Somewhat unsure what your goal is here. Based on the referenced URL there seems to only be a solid state of over 1600 quotes. If you're trying to only use 1 random quote you're going about it the wrong way. On load you should pull the data then randomly decide the quote based on the length of the array and I would cache all the quotes and build a second array just of the quotes you used so your random wont repeat.

Comment: Would the axios-cache adapter be a good choice for caching?

Comment: I havent played with it wouldnt know without researching. I would ideally use `localstorage` to store the quotes to and reference accordingly. Also depends if there are areas you're going to use it might look into building Context for it.

Comment: I am using localstorage. I try it, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the map() method as it returns an array not a single object. All you need is to get the first item in the returned array, then format and display it. Something like this:

```
     let arrayOfQuotes = [];

        const data = await axios.get("https://type.fit/api/quotes");

        arrayOfQuotes = data.data;

        if(arrayOfQuotes.length > 0){
           const quote = (
              <div key={arrayOfQuotes[0].id}>
                 <h3>{arrayOfQuotes[0].text}</h3>
                 <p>{arrayOfQuotes[0].author}</p>
              </div>);
          setQuote(quote);
       }
```

By the way, the API endpoint you are using returns a list while you need a single quote. I think there should be another endpoint which provides a single quote. You need to check the API documents if it has one.

Comment: I tried it and it does not display anything. I put a console.log(quote) in front of setQuote in the code and this keeps spinning: ```{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: 'div', key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …} ```

Comment: Why do you have [quote] in your useEffect()? I think replacing that with [] would solve the spinning issue. Cuz you only want one quote for each page load. right? so it should not fetch a new quote each time state changes.

Comment: It says that currently parameterised requests are not supported. The endpoint works unchanged.

Comment: It now returns only one object, but still does not display it. This is what the debugger says when I delete the quote: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'quote'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.

Comment: About the not displaying the object in the console, I think that's due to tags you're adding to the quote. Try logging only the quote without any tags. Or try to render it to the page instead of logging it to the console.

Comment: and about the warning check this post : https://betterprogramming.pub/stop-lying-to-react-about-missing-dependencies-10612e9aeeda

Comment: Thank you for your help! It works finally! My problem was that I tried to print out quote[index] and not just quote.

Comment: great. I am glad that I could help.